# Use of magic __set() function in base class

Tags: php, yii

I have tried in yii frame work adding set function in CController and try to add property in controller's object but it gives error

Can i user base class's __set function to set property of a instance.

```
 Class  Base {
     public function __set() {
         $this->$name = $value;
     }
}
Class  SubClass1 extends Base{

}
Class  SubClass2 extends Base {

}
```

I create instance of SubClass1 or SubClass2 and i want to add property dynamically. Is it possible.

Comment: If the property is protected and defined only in the subclasses, I think that's possible.

Comment: Have you tried it? This is a Q+A site don't forget, not a live PHP interpreter.

Comment: I have tried in yii frame work adding set function in CController and try to add property in controller's object but it gives error thats why i ask. @Clive

Comment: Good stuff @Md.Yusuf, probably a good idea to edit that info into the question to provide context

Answer (score 0):

yes you can unless the property is private

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can place your magic function your your class structure. Magic functions normally calls even if you are not defining in class file.

So, if you not create __set() in your class file, it won't affect much. But, if you want to do some extra things while setting under object then it will be helpful.

Also, __set() function need two parameter, $name and $value. Please refer following url,

[__set() magic function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.set)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed, the following will demonstrate:

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    private $vars = array();

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        echo "Setting $name: $value<br />";
        $this->vars[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        echo "Getting $name<br />";
        return isset($this->vars[$name]) ? $this->vars[$name] : null;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {}

$bar = new Bar();

$bar->baz = 'baz';
echo $bar->baz;
```

Which will output:

> Setting baz: baz
>
> Getting baz
>
> baz

Answer (score -2):

```
     class Base {
     protected $data;
     public function __construct() {
     $this->someMethodBaseClass();
     }
     protected function someMethodBaseClass() {
     $this->data = 123456;
     }
     }



    class subclass1 extends Base{
    public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    }
    public function getData() {
    return $this->data;  

    }
  }
```

Comment: Just spamming a question with code is hardly helpful.